# VS2008 Reports vs. Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting

I just noticed, while adding a new item to Solution Explorer, a Report item in the selection list. It seems to be a reporting component when I opened it. Is this a new Add-On in Visual Studio 2008 and can it be used as a full-feature reporting component instead of Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been available since Visual Studio 2005.  Yes, it's a full reporting tool that you can use.  See [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services).  It takes a little getting used to and it doesn't have all of the bells and whistles of Crystal Reports but I find it much less aggravating to use than CR.  You can run the reports from SQL Server Reporting Services or you can create standalone reports that can be run from within your .NET application.

Comment: Does the SQL Server 2008 Express Edition include Reporting Services and is it a more complete version?

Comment: I believe you can get it as an additional download.  Check out http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/reporting.aspx.  I'm not sure what the differences are between versions.